# Xfces user defined action is not working whereas it's working in console

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, xfce

I'd like to use a user defined action in Xfce for converting pictures.

Therefore i wrote

```
for i in %F; do filename=$(basename "$i"); 
    extension="${filename##*.}";
    filename="${filename%.*}";
    convert -resize 1024 $i $filename-1024px.$extension;
done
```

But this one don't works...whereas when i execute it in a shell (* instead of %F) it's working.

```
for i in *; do filename=$(basename "$i"); 
    extension="${filename##*.}";
    filename="${filename%.*}";
    convert -resize 1024 $i $filename-1024px.$extension;
done
```

I think there is a problem with the storage of the variables?

Edit:

This still works:

```
for i in %F;
    do filename=$(basename "$i");
    extension="${filename##*.}";
    notify-send "$filename";
done
```

After change to the following code it stops working:

```
for i in %F;
    do filename=$(basename "$i");
    extension="${filename##*.}";
    filename="${filename%.*}";
    notify-send "$filename";
done
```

Comment: What is `%F` supposed to be?

Comment: @EtanReisner %F — The paths to all selected files. E.g. if i do `for i in %F; do notify-send "$i"; done` i get the full path displayed of all files that are selected.

Comment: That's an xfce action thing? What about that snippet isn't working then? Are you getting `%F` literally in the script?

Comment: Yes this is an Xfce [action](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions). I normally get `%F` and it's working with simple stuff like example above or `for i in %F; do convert -resize 1024 $i $i; done`

Comment: So what **exactly** about that above snippet isn't working?

Comment: @EtanReisner I edited to try to show when the error occurs.

Comment: What does "stops working" mean exactly? Does it error? Does it not run at all? Does it eat your cat?

Comment: Oh! I bet the xfce formatter is being stupid and expanding `%.` or erroring on it. You either need to escape it or, possibly, you need to use a different way to get what you want there because you just can't use `%` in the script. (`basename` will strip an extension too optionally so you could invert the first two lines and use `$(basename "$i" "$extension"`)`).

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks a lot! With escaping it works `filename="${filename%%.*}";`

Comment: File that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In Xfces user defined actions `%` must be escaped. So you need here to use

```
filename="${filename%%.*}";
```

instead of

```
filename="${filename%.*}";
```